# Spark extracting values from a Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe

```
val transactions_with_counts = sqlContext.sql(
  """SELECT user_id AS user_id, category_id AS category_id,
  COUNT(category_id) FROM transactions GROUP BY user_id, category_id""")
```

I'm trying to convert the rows to Rating objects but since x(0) returns an array this fails

```
val ratings = transactions_with_counts
  .map(x => Rating(x(0).toInt, x(1).toInt, x(2).toInt))
```

> error: value toInt is not a member of Any

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Lets start with some dummy data:

```
val transactions = Seq((1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3)).toDF("user_id", "category_id")

val transactions_with_counts = transactions
  .groupBy($"user_id", $"category_id")
  .count

transactions_with_counts.printSchema

// root
// |-- user_id: integer (nullable = false)
// |-- category_id: integer (nullable = false)
// |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

There are a few ways to access `Row` values and keep expected types:

1. Pattern matching

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

   transactions_with_counts.map{
     case Row(user_id: Int, category_id: Int, rating: Long) =>
       Rating(user_id, category_id, rating)
   }
   ```
2. Typed `get*` methods like `getInt`, `getLong`:

   ```
   transactions_with_counts.map(
     r => Rating(r.getInt(0), r.getInt(1), r.getLong(2))
   )
   ```
3. `getAs` method which can use both names and indices:

   ```
   transactions_with_counts.map(r => Rating(
     r.getAs[Int]("user_id"), r.getAs[Int]("category_id"), r.getAs[Long](2)
   ))
   ```

   It can be used to properly extract user defined types, including `mllib.linalg.Vector`. Obviously accessing by name requires a schema.
4. Converting to statically typed `Dataset` (Spark 1.6+ / 2.0+):

   ```
   transactions_with_counts.as[(Int, Int, Long)]
   ```

Comment: Which is the most efficient way out of above four approaches you have mentioned....?

Comment: @Dilan Pattern matching statically typed options might be slower (the latter one has some other performance implication). `getAs[_]` and `get*` should be similar but are painful to use.

Comment: 1. What does it mean by "the latter one has some other performance implication"...?
2. Does getAs[_] and get* better than the pattern matching in terms of performance ?

Comment: I'm using the 1st method described above for `DataFrame` having **nullable** columns like this `case Row(usrId: Int, usrName: String, null, usrMobile: Int) => ...` and `case Row(usrId: Int, usrName: String, usrAge: Int, null) => ...` which results in long *case expressions* (and I have several cases). Is there a cleaner way (more condensed, less boilerplate / repetitive stuff) to do it? Please answer with an example.

Comment: Excellent answers Mr 0323.

Answer (score 8):

Using Datasets you can define Ratings as follows:

```
case class Rating(user_id: Int, category_id:Int, count:Long)
```

The Rating class here has a column name 'count' instead of 'rating' as zero323 suggested. Thus the rating variable is assigned as follows:

```
val transactions_with_counts = transactions.groupBy($"user_id", $"category_id").count

val rating = transactions_with_counts.as[Rating]
```

This way you will not run into run-time errors in Spark because your
Rating class column name is identical to the 'count' column name generated by  Spark on run-time.