# addition of two dataframe integer values in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

So I'm new to both Scala and Spark so it may be kind of a dumb question...
I have the following code :

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).toDF();
df.foreach( value => println( value(0) + value(0) ) );

error: type mismatch;
 found   : Any
 required: String
```

What is wrong with it? How do I tell "this is an integer not an any"?
I tried value(0).toInt but "value toInt is not a member of Any".
I tried List(1:Integer, 2:Integer, 3:Integer) but I can not convert into a dataframe afterward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark `Row` is an untyped container. If you want to extract anything else than `Any` you have to use typed extractor method or pattern matching over the `Row` (see [Spark extracting values from a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33007840/1560062)):

```
df.rdd.map(value => value.getInt(0) + value.getInt(0)).collect.foreach(println)
```

In practice there should be reason to extract these values at all. Instead you can operate directly on the `DataFrame`:

```
df.select($"_1" + $"_1")
```