# How do i convert spark dataframe to RDD and get bag of words

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataframe called article

```
+--------------------+
|     processed_title|
+--------------------+
|[new, relictual, ...|
|[once, upon,a,time..|
+--------------------+
```

I want to flatten it to get it as bag of words.
How could I achieve this using the current situation. I have tried the code below which seems to give me a Type mismatch issue.

```
val bow_corpus = article.select("processed_title").rdd.flatMap(y => y)
```

I eventually want to use this bow_corpus to train a word2vec model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `processed_title` is represented in SQL as `array<string>`:

```
article.select("processed_title").rdd.flatMap(_.getSeq[String](0))
```

There is also `Word2Vec` transformer which can be trained directly on a `DataFrame`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec

val word2Vec = new Word2Vec()
  .setInputCol("processed_title")
  .setOutputCol("vectors")
  .setMinCount(0)
  .fit(article)

word2Vec.findSynonyms("foo", 1)
```

See also [Spark extracting values from a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33007840/1560062)