# Converting datatypes in Spark/Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, data-structures

I have a variable in scala called `a` which is as below

```
scala> a
res17: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([0_42], [big], [baller], [bitch], [shoe] ..)
```

It is an array of lists which contains a single word.

I would like to convert it to a single array consisting of sequence of strings like shown below

```
Array[Seq[String]] = Array(WrappedArray(0_42,big,baller,shoe,?,since,eluid.........
```

Well the reason why I am trying to create an array of single wrapped array is I want to run word2vec model in spark using MLLIB.

The fit() function in this only takes iterable string.

```
scala> val model = word2vec.fit(b)
<console>:41: error: inferred type arguments [String] do not conform to method fit's type parameter bounds [S <: Iterable[String]]
```

Comment: can you provide an example input and an example output how it should be

Comment: Example input is a Array([a],[b],[c],[d]) and output should be Array(wrappedarray(a,b,,c,d))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark extracting values from a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007840/spark-extracting-values-from-a-row)

Answer (score 0):

The sample data you're listing is not an `array of lists`, but an `array of Rows`.  An array of a single `WrappedArray` you're trying to create also doesn't seem to serve any meaningful purpose.

If you want to create an array of all the word strings in your `Array[Row]` data structure, you can simply use a `map` like in the following:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("0_42"), ("big"), ("baller"), ("bitch"), ("shoe"), ("?"), ("since"), ("eliud"), ("win")
).toDF("word")

val a = df.rdd.collect
// a: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array(
//   [0_42], [big], [baller], [bitch], [shoe], [?], [since], [eliud], [win]
// )

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val b = a.map{ case Row(w: String) => w }
// b: Array[String] = Array(0_42, big, baller, bitch, shoe, ?, since, eliud, win)
```

[UPDATE]

If you do want to create an array of a single `WrappedArray`, here's one approach:

```
val b = Array( a.map{ case Row(w: String) => w }.toSeq )
// b: Array[Seq[String]] = Array(WrappedArray(
//   0_42, big, baller, bitch, shoe, ?, since, eliud, win
// ))
```

Comment: Well the reason why I am trying to create an array of single wrapped array is I want to run word2vec model in spark using MLLIB.    The fit() function in this only takes iterable string.  I could create val b ,but I cannot run the model using it....I get the following error scala> val model = word2vec.fit(b)
<console>:41: error: inferred type arguments [String] do not conform to method fit's type parameter bounds [S <: Iterable[String]]
         val model = word2vec.fit(b)

Comment: @vish, `a` as in your original sample data is not a `RDD` but an `Array[Row]`.  Using my sample data, you'll need to `collect` (i.e. df.rdd.collect) in order to get to the exact `Array[Row]` type, in which `toSeq` is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by doing the following

```
val db=a.map{ case Row(word: String) => word }
val model = word2vec.fit( b.map(l=>Seq(l)))
```

Comment: Where does `f` come from?