# Iterate rows and columns in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Spark dataframe that is created dynamically:

```
val sf1 = StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true)
val sf2 = StructField("sector", StringType, nullable = true)
val sf3 = StructField("age", IntegerType, nullable = true)

val fields = List(sf1,sf2,sf3)
val schema = StructType(fields)

val row1 = Row("Andy","aaa",20)
val row2 = Row("Berta","bbb",30)
val row3 = Row("Joe","ccc",40)

val data = Seq(row1,row2,row3)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
```

Now, I need to iterate each row and column in `sqlDF` to print each column, this is my attempt:

```
sqlDF.foreach { row =>
  row.foreach { col => println(col) }
}
```

`row` is type `Row`, but is not iterable that's why this code throws a compilation error in `row.foreach`. How to iterate each column in `Row`?

Comment: For printing dataframe why don't you use sqlDF.show?

Comment: println is just for the question, I need to access column data in the program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark extracting values from a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007840/spark-extracting-values-from-a-row)

Comment: @ShankarKoirala This question is different, it asks how to extract values from columns, the one you refer to is to extract values from Rows

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Consider you have a `Dataframe` like below

```
+-----+------+---+
| name|sector|age|
+-----+------+---+
| Andy|   aaa| 20|
|Berta|   bbb| 30|
|  Joe|   ccc| 40|
+-----+------+---+
```

To loop your **Dataframe** and extract the elements from the **Dataframe**, you can either chose one of the below approaches.

**Approach 1 - Loop using foreach**

Looping a dataframe directly using `foreach` loop is not possible. To do this, first you have to define schema of dataframe using `case class` and then you have to specify this schema to the dataframe.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
case class cls_Employee(name:String, sector:String, age:Int)
val df = Seq(cls_Employee("Andy","aaa", 20), cls_Employee("Berta","bbb", 30), cls_Employee("Joe","ccc", 40)).toDF()
df.as[cls_Employee].take(df.count.toInt).foreach(t => println(s"name=${t.name},sector=${t.sector},age=${t.age}"))
```

Please see the result below :

[image]

**Approach 2 - Loop using rdd**

Use `rdd.collect` on top of your **Dataframe**. The `row` variable will contain each row of **Dataframe** of `rdd` row type. To get each element from a row, use `row.mkString(",")` which will contain value of each row in comma separated values. Using `split` function (inbuilt function) you can access each column value of `rdd` row with index.

```
for (row <- df.rdd.collect)
{   
    var name = row.mkString(",").split(",")(0)
    var sector = row.mkString(",").split(",")(1)
    var age = row.mkString(",").split(",")(2)   
}
```

Note that there are two drawback of this approach.
1. If there is a `,` in the column value, data will be wrongly split to adjacent column. 
 
2. `rdd.collect` is an `action` that returns all the data to the driver's memory where driver's memory might not be that much huge to hold the data, ending up with getting the application failed.

I would recommend to use **Approach 1**.

**Approach 3 - Using where and select**

You can directly use `where` and `select` which will internally loop and finds the data. Since it should not throws Index out of bound exception, an if condition is used

```
if(df.where($"name" === "Andy").select(col("name")).collect().length >= 1)
    name = df.where($"name" === "Andy").select(col("name")).collect()(0).get(0).toString
```

**Approach 4 - Using temp tables**

You can register dataframe as temptable which will be stored in spark's memory. Then you can use a select query as like other database to query the data and then collect and save in a variable

```
df.registerTempTable("student")
name = sqlContext.sql("select name from student where name='Andy'").collect()(0).toString().replace("[","").replace("]","")
```

Comment: Can Approach 1 be used with Pyspark?

Comment: I think it should be (though the syntax will be different), but have never tried in Pyspark. And it also depends whether you use Pandas dataframe or Spark's dataframe in Pyspark @thentangler

Comment: I would prefer to use spark dataframe since pandas would bring the data to the driver. Does `foreach` only work in `rdd` and not dataframes?

Comment: Spark dataframe also bring data into Driver. Use transformations before you call `rdd.foreach` as it will limit the records that brings to Driver. Additionally if you need to have Driver to use unlimited memory you could pass command line argument `--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0`. As per my understanding dataframe.foreach doesn't save our purpose, you have to use rdd.dataframe. @thentangler

Comment: Approach 2 one is not really better than 1, as the `take()` in 1 will also load data into driver's memory. [See docs.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.take.html)

Answer (score 23):

You can convert `Row` to `Seq` with `toSeq`. Once turned to `Seq` you can iterate over it as usual with `foreach`, `map` or whatever you need

```
    sqlDF.foreach { row => 
           row.toSeq.foreach{col => println(col) }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Berta
bbb
30
Joe
Andy
aaa
20
ccc
40
```

Comment: This answer is not working for me but Approach 1 from @Sarath Avanavu answer works.

Comment: Yeah this is shaky because casting the record into something useful is prone to fail, even though standard processing of a dataframe by spark manages casting to even case classes, automatically.

Comment: @Scouto I needed to add a `.collect()` method here before the `.foreach()`, maybe that is what you meant?

Answer (score 7):

You should use `mkString` on your `Row`:

```
sqlDF.foreach { row =>
  println(row.mkString(",")) 
}
```

But note that this will be printed inside the executors JVM's, so norally you won't see the output (unless you work with master = local)

Answer (score 6):

`sqlDF.foreach` is not working for me but Approach 1 from @Sarath Avanavu answer works but it was also playing with the order of the records sometime.

I found one more way which is working

```
df.collect().foreach { row =>
   println(row.mkString(","))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate over the partitions which allows the data to be processed by Spark in parallel and you can do foreach on each row inside the partition.

You can further group the data in partition into batches if need be

```
sqlDF.foreachPartition { partitionedRows: Iterator[Model1] =>     
  if (partitionedRows.take(1).nonEmpty) {
       partitionedRows.grouped(numberOfRowsPerBatch).foreach { batch =>
        batch.foreach { row => 
        .....
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me

```
sqlDF.collect().foreach(row => row.toSeq.foreach(col => println(col)))
```

Comment: While this works, it brings all the Data back to the driver. If you're operating on a large Dataframe, this could crash your application.

Answer (score 0):

simple collect result and then apply foreach

`df.collect().foreach(println)`

Comment: this is the only answer that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

My solution using FOR because it was I need:

Solution 1:

```
case class campos_tablas(name:String, sector:String, age:Int)

for (row <- df.as[campos_tablas].take(df.count.toInt)) 
{ 
     print(row.name.toString)

}
```

Solution 2:

```
for (row <- df.take(df.count.toInt))
{ 
   print(row(0).toString)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Let's assume *resultDF* is the Dataframe.**

```
val resultDF = // DataFrame //
var itr = 0
val resultRow = resultDF.count
val resultSet = resultDF.collectAsList
var load_id = 0
var load_dt = ""
var load_hr = 0

while ( itr < resultRow ){
    col1 = resultSet.get(itr).getInt(0)
    col2 = resultSet.get(itr).getString(1) // if column is having String value
    col3 = resultSet.get(itr).getLong(2) // if column is having Long value

    // Write other logic for your code //

    itr = itr + 1
}
```