# How to assign values from a CSV to individual variables using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'd like first to appologize if this is not the proper way of asking a question but it's my first one.

I have a CSV with 2 columns, one with names and another one with values.

I have imported the CSV as a Scala DataFrame into Spark and I want to assign all the values to individual variables (getting the variable names from the column name).

The DataFrame looks like this (there are more variables and the total number of variables can change)

```
|                name|value|
+--------------------+-----+
|           period_id|  188|
|            homeWork| 0.75|
|             minDays|    7|
...
```

I am able to assign the value of one individual row to a variable using the code below, but I'd like to do it for all the records automatically.

```
val period_id = vbles.filter(vbles("name").equalTo("period_id")).select("value").first().getString(0).toDouble
```

The idea I had was to iterate through all the rows in the DataFrame and run the code above each time, something like

```
for (valName <- name) {
    val valName = vbles.filter(vbles("name").equalTo(valName )).select("value").first().getString(0).toDouble
}
```

I have tried [some ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252670/iterate-rows-and-columns-in-spark-dataframe) of iterating through the rows of the DataFrame but I haven't been successful.

What I'd like to get is as if I'd do this manually

```
val period_id = 188
val homeWork = 0.75
val minDays = 7
...
```

I suppose that there are smarter ways of getting this, but if I could just iterate through the rows it'd be fine, although any solution that works is welcome.

Thanks a lot

Comment: filter studies all the rows automatically, you don't need to do anything else. Instead of `.first().getString(0).toDouble` try `.show()`

Comment: but I can't assign the values to a variable using ```.show()```, right?

Comment: No, show is to see, for this, you can use a collect, the collect return your data as Array, but you don't know the order of your data. Where do you will use your data?

Comment: I am using those values as variables in other parts of the code (the name of the variable is the name in the column name). At the moment the variables are declared manually at the begining of the notebook, but there are quite a few notebooks and are run multiple times changing the values, so it's easier and safer to modify a CSV and copy the values from there

Comment: This solution is not recomended but try it and tall us if it's your solution:
`var ArrayNames: Array[Double] = new Array(name.length)
for (i <- o until name.length) {
    ArrayNames(i) = vbles.filter(vbles("name(i)").equalTo($name )).select("value").first().getString(0).toDouble
}`

Comment: Would all variables exists always? - also, if you want to extract them as variables, I would assume there aren't more than a twenty of them, why do you use a dataframe for that? that is a data structure that is supposed to be sued for distributed computations over millions of  registries. I would just write my own csv reader on plain Scala that builds a case class incrementally by reading the file line by line.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers.
@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm not doing what you mentioned because I'm not that familiar with Scala.
I also didn't think about the scope of the variables, so I don't think that doing what I had in mine works.

I don't have many variables, 30 something, but as I'm using them in several Zeppelin notebooks and I don't need all of them in each notebook I found it better not to call the needed ones each time, but that's what I did.

Comment: At the end I transformed the DF to a map

`val vbles2 = vbles.select($"name", $"value").as[(String, String)].collect.toMap
`
And I declare all the variables calling to the map values

`val period_id = vbles2("period_id")`

Comment: @OGC the map alternative is a good idea, but again I would not read the **CSV** file using a `DataFrame` you are using rocket launcher to nail a nail. Take a look to [`Source`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source.html).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez TBH, this it what I exactly did, not sure if it's still going through the DF before getting the map  `val vbles = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").load(s"$RefDataPath/variables.csv").select($"name", $"value").as[(String, String)].collect.toMap`

Comment: @OGC it is going to the DF. I mean, it is not so bad, but is kind of unnecessary. However, if using **Source** you would need to re implement all the parsing logic, so if you really need spark for other things, then this may just be the simplest way.