# What is the canonical way to create objects from rows of a Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, influxdb, apache-zeppelin

I am using Apache Zeppelin (0.9.0) and Scala (2.11.12). I want to pull some data out of a dataframe and store it to InfluxDB, later to be visualized in Grafana, and cannot figure it out. I'm trying a naive approach with a `foreach` loop. The idea is to iterate through all rows, extract the columns I need, create a Point object (from [this InfluxDB client library](https://github.com/paulgoldbaum/scala-influxdb-client)), and either send it to InfluxDB or add it to a list and then send all the points in bulk, after the loop.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+-----+
|timestamp|sessionId|eventDuration|speed|
+---------+---------+-------------+-----+
|        1|     ses1|          0.0|   50|
|        2|     ses1|          1.0|   50|
|        3|     ses1|          2.0|   50|
```

I've tried to do what is described above:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.paulgoldbaum.influxdbclient._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val influxdb = InfluxDB.connect("172.17.0.4", 8086)
val database = influxdb.selectDatabase("test")

var influxData = new ListBuffer[Point]()
dfAnalyseReport.foreach(row => 
    {
        val point = Point("acceleration")
                    .addTag("speedBin", row.getLong(3).toString)
                    .addField("eventDuration", row.getDouble(2))
        influxData += point
    }
)
val influxDataList = influxData.toList
database.bulkWrite(influxDataList)
```

The only thing I am getting here is a cryptic `java.lang.ClassCastException` with no additional info, neither in the notebook output nor in the logs of the Zeppelin Docker container. The error seems to be somewhere in the foreach, as it appears even when I comment out the last two lines.

I also tried adapting approach 1 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133345/5740426), using a case class for columns, but to no avail. I got it to run without an error, but the resulting list was empty. Unfortunately I deleted that attempt. I could reconstruct it if necessary, but I've spent so much time on this I'm fairly certain I have some fundamental misunderstanding on how this should be done.

One further question: I also tried writing each Point to the DB as it was constructed (instead of in bulk). The only difference is that instead of appending to the `ListBuffer` I did a `database.write(point)` operation. When done outside of the loop with a dummy point, it goes through without a problem - the data ends up in InfluxDB - but inside the loop it results in `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

Could someone point me in the right way? How should I tackle this?

Comment: what's the schema of the dataframe? is the speed column of type int or long? If you use getLong on an int column, you could get a classcastexception.

Comment: You're right, it was an Integer. Changing it to getInt fixed the ClassCastException, and it went through without an error. However, the resulting list and listbuffer were still empty. What gives? Am I missing something with the scope of `influxData`?

Comment: See my answer below. I think using `rdd.map` is better than `df.foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with the RDD map method and collect the results to a list:

```
val influxDataList = dfAnalyseReport.rdd.map(
    row => Point("acceleration")
           .addTag("speedBin", row.getInt(3).toString)
           .addField("eventDuration", row.getDouble(2))
).collect.toList
```

Comment: This did it, thanks! Can you tell me (or suggest some further reading) why my original approach didn't work?

Comment: I'm not too sure, maybe the list buffer doesn't get parallelized well.