# Is it Pandas Dataframe the best ETL code solution when you need to iterate over the rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl

I am doing a proof of concept with Pandas, and I read something that concerns me, about NOT iterate over the rows, because is a antipattern, slow and difficult. But in my case I really need to iterate over each Row, because my ETL proccess do a row aggregation based in some conditions( client identification and day basically ).

So, I receive million of rows of different clients in a table with more than 100 columns, and these millions of rows turns in hundreds, thousands rows in datawarehouse, resulting in a row per client daily, and in this final table I do some calculations( sum, division, percentage ) based on multiples row columns.

In my StageTable the rows have two datetime columns in GMT( begintime and endtime ) with seconds precision, and in Data Warehouse have two int columns to represent date in localtime with day precision, so I need to iterate over all rows, transform datetime in int, and apply timezone( customer timezone is in other table ). So '2021-03-10 02:01:33' in Stage became '20210309' in DW because of timezone.

```
select * from stageTable where customer = ? and begin_datetime > ?  and begin_datetime < ? 
and end_datetime > ? and end_datetime < ?

PseudoCode iterating over million of rows: 
    NewColumn = If( column9 == 'AAA' )? ( column5 + column99 + column110 )
    AggregationNewColumn += NewColumn
    If( ChangeUser or ChangeDay):
       RecordRow()
       AggregationNewColumn = 0
       continue
```

So, if one of the customer's users generate in Stage 1200 registers, 800 beginning in day 10 and ending in day 10, 100 beginning in day 10 and ending in day 11 and 300 beginning in day 11 and ending in day 11, in Data Warehouse this will be represented  by 3 aggregate rows( begin:20210310/end:20210310 - begin:20210310/end:20210311 - begin:20210311/end:20210311 )

Using C# inside SSIS is very fast to do that, tens of million rows read in few minutes, but pandas dataframe is slow to iterate over rows and not recommended to iterate. Is it recommended to continue using pandas dataframe for my case or do you suggest another python lib or even another language to do that? ( I am looking for a ETL pure code )

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way to solve it.  If you could mock up some data, add it to your question, as well as mock up the desired output it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Loading all data in memory is the *worst* solution, especially when you have so much data it can't fit in memory. What you describe can be solved with a simple `SELECT .. WHERE .. GROUP BY`

Comment: Since you already have a data warehouse and, I assume, a well indexed fact table, why are you trying to use Pandas instead of querying the fact table?

Comment: Chris, I do a "select * from stageTable where customer = ? and day > ? and day < ? order by user, day" and I iterate over all rows of this select, iterating and doing agregations and calculations over all rows, recording a register in data warehouse when change the day or the user

Comment: Panagiotis, I wish to use Pandas to pass the data from Stage( SQL Server ) to a Data Warehouse( SQL Server ). I don't bring everything to memory, I use chunks

Comment: Panagiotis, I forget to mention that in Stage the date is a datetime GMT with seconds precision, and in my date warehouse I have a int that represent day precision in local time, so I need to iterate over all rows, transform the datetime in date, and apply timezone to each register( timezone value is in other table ). So, '2021-03-10 01:05:32' become '20210309' in data warehouse because timezone

Comment: I don't think pandas is your best solution.  If you are moving large quantities of data from one database to another, you likely want to use your database to do so.  For example, in Oracle, you can use replication, Golden Gate, or a number of other options.  Assuming you are certain you you want to use pandas and iterate over rows, use df.itterows().  Or, use pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(). And, the if statement in your code should be in the first sql select statement if possible.

Comment: @gomeslhlima. What that  means "ETL pure code" ? If you use ETL you have to use the function of the black box (excepted if pandas is in the black box) , if you use a ELT you have to use the SQL function of the RDMS. Like cadvena said If you want to use pandas you cannot use for that.

Comment: @cadvena, I read a large quantity of data, but I do many transformations and aggregations to in the Data Warehouse to hundreds of rows in Stage became only one row in Data Warehouse with few columns

Comment: @phili_b, when I said 'pure code' I am saying not use visual framework like SSIS, Pentaho, Talend, etc. and use only not visual programming language, like Python with Pandas, C# with other lib, Java, C++, etc. Sorry for the misunderstanding in my term

Comment: @gomeslhlima. Even in SQL to iterate rows is not a good idea, you have to use aggregate function. The only software where you can use iterate with power is proprietary ETL that I've named by black box. Or if the datas and the structure could be iterated : I don't know if this a solution but look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252670/iterate-rows-and-columns-in-spark-dataframe

Comment: @phili_b, I may be wrong, but I think that SSIS iterate row by row, because in my select I don't do Group By or other aggregation( select * from stageTable where customer = ? and begin_datetime > ?  and begin_datetime < ? 
and end_datetime > ? and end_datetime < ? ), I do a simple select with order by user and date, and even with that simple select the SSIS process millions of rows in few minutes. But I may be wrong, I don't know what SSIS box do internally

Comment: @gomeslhlima "not visual programming language, like Python with Pandas, C# with other lib, Java, C++". Are looking for something like Pro*C? But it's for Oracle.

Comment: @phili_b, one reason for me think that SSIS do row by row is that I use a C# component that has a method called in each row iteration to do this algorithm of calculate new columns aggregate columns based in User and Date

Comment: @gomeslhlima. You have to change your mind :) You cannot mix concepts between technologies if it's not proposed : to see SSIS to have a solution in Python cannot work. The architecture, languages, structures are differents.

Comment: @phili_b, I aggre with you. I beginning with Python this week, so I am trying to do the things with my SSIS/C# experience, but I will read you suggestion, in addition to use more SQL functions to group/aggregate. Thank you so much for all the help that I receive from all users in this post :)

Comment: In this case, pandas is a good tool for processing large data sets.  In the pandas docs, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html, you will find tools like apply (to apply a function), query, where, groupby, pivot, combine, join, merge.   If you are performing math on columns or rows, a DataFrame is great.  You can also perform most SQL like functions on DataFrames.  To aggregate columns, you don't need to iterate; use the aggregate() method.  See if the methods in the docs meet your needs.   If not, provide a specific data manipulation scenario with sample data.