# Convert spark dataframe map column to json

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, json4s

I have a dataframe with below schema and sample record

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- matches: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)

+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|name           |matches                                                                                   |
+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CVS_Extra      |Map(MLauer -> 1, MichaelBColeman -> 1, OhioFoodbanks -> 1, 700wlw -> 1, cityofdayton -> 1)|
```

I am trying to convert map type column to json using below code(json4s library):

```
val d = countDF.map( row => (row(0),convertMapToJSON(row(1).asInstanceOf[Map[String, Int]]).toString()))
```

But fails with

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.javaClass(JavaMirrors.scala:555)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToJava$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:1210)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anonfun$classToJava$1.apply(JavaMirrors.scala:1202)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache$$anonfun$toJava$1.apply(TwoWayCaches.scala:50)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.Gil$class.gilSynchronized(Gil.scala:19)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse.gilSynchronized(JavaUniverse.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.TwoWayCaches$TwoWayCache.toJava(TwoWayCaches.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.classToJava(JavaMirrors.scala:1202)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:194)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.getClassFromType(ScalaReflection.scala:682)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$dataTypeFor(ScalaReflection.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:607)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits$class.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:33)

Scala Version - 2.11, json4s-jackson_2.11  & spark 2.2.0
```

Can anyone please suggest how to overcome this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your code fails because you incorrectly use `apply` method. You should use for example:

```
countDF.map(row => 
  (row.getString(0), convertMapToJSON(getMap[String, Int](1)).toString())
)
```

For more see [Spark extracting values from a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33007840/9613318).

But all you need is `select` / `withColumn` with `to_json`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_json

countDF.withColumn("matches", to_json($"matches"))
```

and if your function uses more complex logic use `udf`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val convert_map_to_json = udf(
  (map: Map[String, Int]) => convertMapToJSON(map).toString
)

countDF.withColumn("matches", convert_map_to_json($"matches"))
```