# how to take 2 values from array and put it as pair and set count to 1 map function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I have RDD as `Array[(a, b), (a, c), (a, d)]`. I want to map it as `((a, b), 1), ((a, c), 1), ((a, d), 1)` and reduce it.

I have tried `val sol2 = sol1.map{r => ((r._1, r._2), 1)}` and `val sol2 = sol1.map{case (val1, val2) => ((val1, val2), 1)}`, both are not working

For code `val sol2 = sol1.map{case (val1, val2) => ((val1, val2), 1)}`, I am getting error as:

```
notebook:2: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val sol2 = sol1.map{case (val1, val2) => ((val1, val2), 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tells you that `sol1` is some kind (`Seq` / `RDD` / `Dataset` - impossible to say without seeing the rest of the code) of structure of `Row`, hence `Tuple2` pattern will never match.

If you want to stick with pattern matching you'll have to match the full structure, including the values:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

sol1.map{case Row(val1: Seq[String], val2: Seq[String]) => ((val1, val2), 1)}
```

Reference [Spark extracting values from a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33007840)