# how to pass a value dynamically from a data frame to Spark sql query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to pass the value(timestamp) from the data frame to a query using the below code but I am getting this error "conversion failed when converting date and time character to string".

I am passing the below timestamp to my query and it should compare the date from the employee table from column header__timestamp

Timestamp: 2023-07-5 13:29:38:876

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

val ETLMetadatadate = spark.sql("select * from metadatatable")

var finaldate = ETLMetadatadate.head
//finaldate.show() we are getting below timestamp from above dataframe
//2023-07-5 13:29:38:876

val query = s"""( SELECT
Ename,
ecompany,
sal

FROM Employee e

WHERE e.header_timestamp >= '${finaldate}') AS C)""".stripMargin

val config = Config(Map(
"url"  -> "example.database.windows.net"
"databaseName" -> "testdatabase"
"querycustom" -> query
"user" -> "sample"
"password" ->"1234"
"connectionTimeout" ->"5"
"querytimeout" -> "5"
))

import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
val collection =sqlcontext.read.sqlDB(config)
collection.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("testtable")
```

Comment: What's the type of `finalDate`? It's not a `String`, it's a `Row`. You need to extract the string value you want from the row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark extracting values from a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007840/spark-extracting-values-from-a-row)